# $_FILES['file_import']['tmp_name']) returns only folder name but not file name

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a php web app that I deploy to multiple servers.  It works on my local installation as well as every other server I put it on.

But on the current server I'm deploying to, I'm having trouble with all of the file upload features.

When trying to debug it, I realized they are failing when trying to get the finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE).

Example: a form has an upload field called "file_import". I put in the following line of code into the shared import function.

```
die(print_r($_FILES['file_import']));
```

On my local installation, it returns:

```
Array
(
    [name] => US Capital Division.csv
    [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php3B7C.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 1268
)
1
```

Uploading the same file on the current deployment it returns:

```
Array
(
    [name] => US Capital Division.csv
    [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJdRZDW
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 1268
)
1
```

They both say they have no errors, but the deployment server only gives the folder name for the tmp_name value, while the local installation gives the temp folder AND file name.   So when my code try $_FILES['file_import']['tmp_name'] it errors.

I feel like it has to be server setting or folder setting, but I can't find anything on the web as to what would cause that.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you think `/tmp/phpJdRZDW` is a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `phpJdRZDW` inside `[tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJdRZDW` is not a folder... It's just a temporary file name while the file sits inside the `/tmp/` folder (waiting to be moved and [usually] renamed).

Comment: Oops... Or, what @Musa said. Kinda. ;)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  If that's just the file name, then the issue seems to be with using finfo to get the FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE.  I put in a die statement to output the mime type.  When I upload a csv file on my local installation, the mime type returns as text/plain.  But when I do it on the deployment server, it returns empty.  And it does that for every file type I try to upload.  I checked phpinfo for several servers.  They all show fileinfo support is enabled, but the "problem server" doesn't show a version number.  Could that be it?

Comment: If `finfo()` isn't available or working, you could always try [`mime_content_type($file)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)... Example: `print mime_content_type('/tmp/phpJdRZDW');` I know it's listed as being "deprecated as the PECL extension Fileinfo provides the same functionality (and more) in a much cleaner way" but if Fileinfo isn't available to you, no reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I only have finfo on this server, not mime_content_type.  But it turns out on this version, I need to use FILEINFO_MIME not FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE. I was then able to get the file extension and prevent the function from erroring.  Your comments really helped me not chase dead ends though, thank you.